# Random numberGenerator

Tags: java, random, attributes, private

For my assignment, I need to write the following attribute:

Write a class Deck. A Deck has the following private attribute:

A static Random numberGenerator.

Initialize the Random numberGenerator "in place" (i.e. on the same line as its declaration) with a reference to a Random object created with the seed 123.

I am confused on how to proceed. I have tried to initialize the attribute, but I don't think I'm doing the correct thing.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {

  // Declare the private attributes

  private static double getRandomNumber(int seed) {

    Random number = new Random(seed);
  }
```

Comment: I've got a feeling, you'll need a lot more code. what have you tried? what didn't work? what error did you get? what were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: you just want to create random number right ?

Comment: The declared `Random number` is in the scope of the `getRandomNumber` function. You have already put the comment where you want the private attribute, so declare it there. You can declare it "in place" there as well.

Comment: @OnkarMusale Yes, as per the instruction of my assignment stated above.

Comment: @Raven221221221 Sorry, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: @Elizabeth when you declare the `Random number` variable, you are doing it inside a method, meaning `number` stops existing when you return from the method, and you are creating a `new Random` object everytime. This also means that if you call `getRandomNumber` with the same parameter, you will get the same number (you will get the first number from the same seed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute belongs to the class, not to a method, so you should declare it outside of any method.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {

    // Declare the private attributes
    private static Random numberGenerator = new Random(123);

    // other attributes and methods follow
}
```

Comment: Should there be a static after private since it is a static method?

Comment: @Elizabeth Yes, I updated my answer. (Declaring the variable `static` will make only one Random object for the entire class, and each Deck object will share that one. Without `static`, each Deck object would create its own Random object.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no return statement in the `getRandomNumber` method. Attributes need to be declared for the `Class` and not inside a method. I think this might be what you are after.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Deck {
    private static Random number = new Random(123); // declare and initialize a Ranom object

    public static double getRandomNumber(){
        return number.nextDouble(); // return the next value
    }
}
```